# CSS does not apply to table rows

Tags: css, jsf, jakarta-ee

I am trying to make odd and even rows having different color. Here is my code:

```
 <h:head>
    <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="styles.css"  /> 
    <title>Facelet Title</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:form>
        <h:dataTable   id="accountsTable" value="#{currentCustomer.accounts}" var="accounts" styleClass="accountsTable" headerClass="accountsTableHeader" rowClasses="accountsTableOddRow,accountsTableEvenRow" >
            <h:column>
                <f:facet name="header">Account Number</f:facet>
                    #{accounts.accountNumber}
            </h:column>
            <h:column>
                <f:facet name="header">Currency</f:facet>
                    #{accounts.accountCurrency}
            </h:column>
            <h:column>
                <f:facet name="header">IBAN</f:facet>
                    #{accounts.iban}
            </h:column>
            <h:column>
                <f:facet name="header">Account Number</f:facet>
                    #{accounts.accountNumber}
            </h:column>
        </h:dataTable>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
```

and the css file:

```
root { 
    display: block;
}


.accountsTable{   
  border-collapse:collapse;
   border:1px solid #000000;
   background-color: red;
}

.accountsTableHeader{
       background:none repeat scroll 0 0 #B5B5B5;
   border-bottom:1px solid #000000;  
   padding:2px;
}

.accountsTableOddRow{
   text-align:center;
  background:none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFFF;   
}

.accountsTableEvenRow{
   text-align:center;
   background:none repeat scroll 0 0 #D3D3D3;
}
```

And my file organization:

[image]

But all rows are still white. Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks

Comment: Why you don't use `tr:nth(2)` selector?

Comment: @YD1m i do not know what is that? Is this about css or about the code?

Comment: This is css selector.

Comment: @Andy thank you i just had a chance to try your solution and it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use

```
<h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="styles.css"  />
```

You need to do the following. Create a folder called `resources` under `Web Pages` and place the folder `css` in it. Your styles are not being applied because it's looking in that folder (`resources`) for the `css` folder.

[Check this link](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/how-to-include-cascading-style-sheets-css-in-jsf/) to sort of see a visual description of what I mean. The first picture you see (the directory one).

Alternatively you can do

```
<h:outputStylesheet name="/css/styles.css"  />
```

Also check this link to see how library should really be used.

[What is the JSF resource library for and how should it be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11988415/what-is-the-jsf-resource-library-for-and-how-should-it-be-used)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this css selectors:

```
tr:nth-child(even) {
   text-align:center;
   background:#D3D3D3;

}
tr:nth-child(odd) {
   text-align:center;
    background:#FFFFFFF;
}
```

Comment: thanks but doesnt work either. do i need to change anything else in the html code?